Logarithmic Spiral motion of a particle
Is this motion a central force motion when beta=omega.The particle is moving in the logarithmic spiral 

No, not a central force.

@trula prove it. in an answer.

I don't know who is flagging this question as homework problem. Yes this is from problem sheet but I am asking the different question related to it. The moderator doesn't know how to flag the questions appropriately.

I don't know who is flagging this question as homework problem. You can see this in the edit history. It was John Rennie, the highest- reputation user on this site.

So a central force, $\vec F$, requires a radial force, which means a radial acceleration, $\vec a$.
To show that, you show $\vec a \times \vec r = 0$...which sounds messy, or use the dot product to get $\cos\theta_{a, r} = 1$. Actually, in 2D the cross product is a pseudoscalar, so it's not as bad as I first thought.
Another approach, since we have time parametrized curve, is the Frenet-Serret formalism (I just google'd "vector curve TNB", since I can't neither spell nor remember anything French, in spite of 7 years of classes). That gives: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet–Serret_formulas
Though, now I see that is too much.
The choice now is work in polar coordinates, which brings in a lot of formalism about local basis vectors--I will skip that and grind it Cartesian...and I am setting $\omega=1$...you can put it in at then end by requiring only terms of the form ($\omega^2 f, \omega f', f''$) in the acceleration):
$$ \vec r(t) = (f(t)\cos t, f(t)\sin t) $$
$$ \vec v(t) = (
f\sin t + f'\cos t,
-f\cos t + f'\sin t) $$
$$ \vec a(t) =
\Big(
(-f\cos t + f'\sin t) +
(f'\sin t + f''\cos t),
(f\sin t - f'\cos t) +
(-f'\cos t + f''\sin t)
\Big) $$
where ($r_0=1$):
$$ f(t) = e^{bt} $$
$$ f'(t) = $$...
wait, lets set $b=1$, too:
$$ f''=f'=f $$
so:
$$ \vec r(t) = f(\cos t, \sin t) $$
$$ \vec v(t) = f(
\sin t + \cos t,
-\cos t + \sin t) $$
$$ \vec a(t) =
f\Big(
(\cos t + \sin t) +
(\sin t + \cos t),
(\sin t - \cos t) +
(-\cos t + \sin t)
\Big) $$
$$ \vec a(t) =
2f\Big(\cos t + \sin t, \sin t - \cos t 
\Big) $$
That's not so bad!
So now compute the pseudoscalar product:
$$ \Pi = \vec a \times \vec r = a_xr_y - a_yr_x $$
$$ \Pi \propto
\cos t (\sin t - \cos t) - \sin t (\cos t + \sin t) = -1 \ne 0
$$
omg, that was a surprise.
You can fill in the factors of $\omega^2$, $r_0$, and $b$ as needed.

Not a central force !!

The reason I set everything to 1 was so I could finish before the question was closed, I hate when a fun problem is closed out from under me. Obv. we don't want "do my homework" question , we're not Chat-GPT. But the point of homework problems is to grind in some physics principles, and the point of PSE is to help ppl understand physics principles, so that's a conflict right there. My answer addressed principles, and if you're in Physics 1 and show up with pseudo scalars and the TNB in your answer, teach is giving you a $|0\rangle$ anyway.

Even knowing that you can set everything to 1 and put them in later is a huge red-flag in a beginner's homework. Insta-$F$.
